# Google Maps iOS Current location default

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

Does anyone know how i can set the default camera position to users current location?
Thanks.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 56.8, longitude: 14.8, zoom: 13)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try these codes it will help you

```
 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    self.googleMapView.delegate = self;

    GMSCameraPosition *sydney = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                            longitude:longitude
                                                                 zoom:10];

    [_googleMapView animateToLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(longitude, longitude)];
    [self.googleMapView setMyLocationEnabled:YES];
    [_googleMapView setCamera:sydney];
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the example code in swift:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()    
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!,
                                          longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!,
                                          zoom: 15.0)
    self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
```